# Web Part not working !! why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have written the jquery to create a web part zone for every tab in a page layout.The tabs have come and there is a web part zone but it is not working and the web part zone is also viewable before editing page.

```
    <script>
$( document ).ready(function() {InsertTabs();});

function InsertTabs(){  

    var val=["Tab1","Tab2"];
    var attrID = ""; 
    var activeTabFade = ""; 
    var activeTabVar = "";  
    var index = 0;
    for(value in val){

        var title = value;              
        if(index == 0) {
            activeTabFade = "in"; activeTabVar = "active";
        }               
        $("#TopSPTabs").append('<li class="'+activeTabVar+'"><a href="#Tab'+index+'" id="TabHead'+index+'" data-toggle="tab">'+title+'</a></li>').after('<div class="tab-pane fade '+activeTabFade+ ' ' +activeTabVar+'" id="Tab'+index+'"></div>');                
        var webPart = '<div class="ms-SPZoneLabel"><span class="ms-webpart-zone-title ms-noWrap">Zone 1</span></div><div ondragenter="MSOLayout_MoveWebPartDragZoneEnter(this, event);" ondragover="MSOLayout_MoveWebPartStopEventBubble(event);" class="ms-SPZone ms-webpart-zone ms-fullWidth " id="MSOZone" zoneID="g_74D304E354064D6780C33FA9DE8BF9A2" zoneTitle="Zone 1" orientation="Vertical" onclick="WzClick(event, &#39;g_74D304E354064D6780C33FA9DE8BF9A2&#39;)" cellspacing="10px" class="ms-webpart-zone ms-fullWidth"><div orientation="Vertical" ondragenter="MSOLayout_MoveWebPartDragEnter(this);" ondragover="MSOLayout_MoveWebPartDragOver(event, this, "False");" style="vertical-align:top;width:;min-width:;padding:8px;"><div class="ms-SPButton ms-WPAddButton" onclick="CoreInvoke(&#39;ShowWebPartAdder&#39;, &#39;g_74D304E354064D6780C33FA9DE8BF9A2&#39;);return false;"><a href="javascript:" onclick="CoreInvoke(&#39;ShowWebPartAdder&#39;, &#39;g_74D304E354064D6780C33FA9DE8BF9A2&#39;);return false;"><span>Add a Web Part</span></a></div></div><div orientation="Vertical" ondragenter="MSOLayout_MoveWebPartDragEnter(this);" ondragover="MSOLayout_MoveWebPartDragOver(event, this, 'False');" align="center" valign="middle" id="MSOZone_EmptyZoneCell" data-iszonecell="true" style="height:10px;padding:0;">&#160;<span class="ms-spzonecaption" name="MSOZoneCell_emptyZoneText" webPartsInZone="0">&#160;<br></span></div></div>';               
        $("#Tab" + index).append((webPart));
        activeTabFade = ""; 
        activeTabVar = ""; 
        index++;

    }
}
</script>
<style>.tab-content{margin-top:10px;} .tab-pane{margin-top:0 !important;}</style>
<div class="tab-content" id="tabContents"><ul id="TopSPTabs" class="nav nav-tabs"></ul></div></div><div class="ms-clear"></div>
```

The page with the created page layout in edit mode.
[image: The page with the created page layout in edit mode]

The page with created page layout without edit mode.
[image]

Comment: Thank you ! Somebody help out..

Comment: Is my function right?

Comment: What is the desired outcome? You are adding exactly what you see in the second image to the page and it's not going to hide because you are calling it after the page runs and hides what is supposed to be hidden no?

Comment: How do call it before page runs?The add a webpart is also not working why?